# C# Await Call throws exception depending on function calling it

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, async-await, windows-phone-8.1

I'm building an app for Windows Phone that make a request to a server and retrieves some JSON text and displays the information to the user.

I'm allowing the user to either enter the search string manually, or letting them scan it from a QR code using the ZXing.NET library.

I have to XAML pages, one for the text entry and one for scanning the QR code. Once I have the search string I navigate to my display page where I try to read the information from the website. From the text entry XAML page it works just fine, from the QR code XAML page I get an First Chance Exception of Type Exception.

Here is how I call the display page from the text entry:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PartDisplayPage), cleanedString);
```

From the QR code page I've actually commented out the QR code reader and just have this in an AppBar button:

```
 this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PartDisplayPage), "144-2227");
```

In the `PartDisplayPage`'s `OnNavigatedTo` function I have the following

```
this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
pInfo = new PartInfoJSON(e.Parameter as string);
await progressbar.ShowAsync();
await pInfo.getPartInfo();
await progressbar.HideAsync();
```

The program makes it to the pInfo.getPartInfo() function which looks like this

```
//create url
string serviceURL = ...;

try
{
    var resp = await MakeAsyncRequest(serviceUrl, "");
    ProductInfo t = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductInfo>(resp);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
  //set stuff to Default value strings for checking later
}
```

The MakeAsync Request I think I found here on StackOverFlow looks like this

```
 public static Task<string> MakeAsyncRequest(string url, string contentType)
 {
     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
     //request.ContentType = contentType;
     request.Method = "GET";

     Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                              request.BeginGetResponse,
                              asyncResult => request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
                              (object)null);

      return task.ContinueWith(t => ReadStreamFromResponse(t.Result));
 }
```

And the ReadFromStreamResponse:

```
 private static string ReadStreamFromResponse(WebResponse response)
    {
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            //Need to return this response 
            string strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            return strContent;
        }
    }
```

So I don't know what is causing the issue. If I use the search page and type in 144-2227 it works just fine, if I hardcode the test into the ScanPage it throws an exception that doesn't get caught in my try catch block. If anyone has any insights I'd be thankful.

Comment: I think that your MakeAsyncRequest is waaay more complex than it needs to be. Check this out for example: https://gist.github.com/igrali/bb27d25f42ce1c2d27a2

Comment: With `async-await` you should use `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.FromAsync`. You'll also find that most (if not all) asynchronous APIs have a task returning method.

Comment: Have you tried Fiddler to see what's going on the wire.

Comment: Could you add the exception's stack trace.

Comment: I'll do that when I get home.

Comment: igrali - I made those changes and it is much easier to read. However, it turns out that wasn't the cause of the problem. It seems it was an issue with the previous pages OnNavigatedFrom handler that threw the error.